# Compilation error while using xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I am getting an error while building an docbook for a user-guide.

> xsltproc --xinclude  ./customization.xsl user-guide.xml warning: failed to load external entity "/usr/share/sgml/docbook/xsl-stylesheets/xhtml-1_1/chunk.xsl"
>
> compilation error: file ./customization.xsl line 6 element import
>   xsl:import : unable to load /usr/share/sgml/docbook/xsl-stylesheets/xhtml-1_1/chunk.xsl
>
> Makefile:13: recipe for target 'all' failed
>
> make: *** [all] Error 5

I have no idea about xml ,please help thanks in advance.

P.S. I am running this command on my linux console.

Comment: The error message is trying to tell you that `customization.xsl` tries to impprt a file `/usr/share/sgml/docbook/xsl-stylesheets/xhtml-1_1/chunk.xsl` which does not exist.

Comment: Yes , I understood that but can you please give a solution to that

Comment: What's your Linux distribution and version? Did you install the `docbook-xsl` package?